# hide the horizontal overflow of a html division

Tags: html, css

`<div id="scroll" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:10000px;">`

The div above will scroll horizontally on user interaction. How do I hide the overflow because I only want the user to see 800px at a time. Is this possible? And if so how.
Sorry if i am unclear

Comment: Your question is not very clear but from what I gathered could you not put it inside a div with a fixed width of 800px then set overflow to auto or hidden?

Comment: the user will click a button and the div will use paralax scrolling to goto the next picture

Comment: @SimonStaton i'm going to check now

Comment: if you are using JQuery to make the scroll happen, maybe post that too.

Comment: I am already using the jQuery scroll on another page and it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="Wrapper">
    <div class="Content">
    </div>
</div>

.Wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    /* or :
    overflow-x: auto;
    */
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.Content {
    width: 10000px;
}
```